# Simulating data for multi-level logit model

Tags: r

I am attempting to simulate multi-level data (random intercept) for testing a multi-level Bayesian logistic regression model. This is what I have done so far:

```
n.country <- 42 #number of units
obs <- rbinom(n.country, 10, .8) #number of obs. per unit
n.obs <- sum(obs) #overall number of obs
country <- rep(1:n.country, obs)

e.country <- rnorm(n.country,0, 3) #country-specific error
e.obs <- rnorm(n.obs, 0, 5) #observation-specific error

# Continuous independent variables
set.seed(666)
X1 = rnorm(n.obs)            
X2 = rnorm(n.obs)
X3 = rnorm(n.obs)          
X4 = rnorm(n.obs)
X5 = rnorm(n.obs)          
X6 = rnorm(n.obs)
X7 = rnorm(n.obs)          
X8 = rnorm(n.obs)

#Dependent variable 
L <- 2*X1 + 3*X2 + 1.75*X3 + 2.5*X4 + 1.5*X5 + 
       3.5*X6 + 0.5*X7 + 1.75*X8 + e.country[country] + e.obs 
##  prob. of the dependent variable described by a linear 
##   combination of covariates and country-specific intercepts 
pr = 1/(1+exp(-L))# pass through an inv-logit function
Y = rbinom(n.obs,1,pr)  #DV described by its probability

#Set up data frame
Test = data.frame(y=Y,x1=X1,x2=X2,x3=X3,x4=X4,x5=X5,x6=X6,
                  x7=X7,x8=X8,country=country)
```

However, when applying my estimator to it, it yields different coefficients than the ones I have set up, and so does the `glmer()` function of the `lme4` Package.
I am both interested in random and fixed effects. My Bayesian estimator looks like this:

```
writeLines("
model{
  for (i in 1:N){
y[i] ~ dbin(p.bound[i], 1)
p.bound[i] <- max(0, min(1, p[i]))
logit(p[i]) <- Xbeta[i]  #likelihood
    Xbeta[i] <- v[country[i]] + beta[1]*x1[i] + beta[2]*x2[i] + beta[3]*x3[i] + beta[4]*x4[i] + beta[5]*x5[i] + beta[6]*x6[i] + beta[7]*x7[i] + beta[8]*x8[i]
  } #linear combination
  for (j in 1:n){
    v[j] ~ dnorm(beta0, prec.tau2) #country-specific intercept
  }
  beta[1] ~ dmnorm(0,0.001) #IV priors
  beta[2] ~ dmnorm(0,0.001)
  beta[3] ~ dmnorm(0,0.001)
  beta[4] ~ dmnorm(0,0.001)
  beta[5] ~ dmnorm(0,0.001)
  beta[6] ~ dmnorm(0,0.001)
  beta[7] ~ dmnorm(0,0.001)
  beta[8] ~ dmnorm(0,0.001)
  beta0 ~ dnorm(0,0.001) 
  prec.tau2 ~dgamma(0.001,0.001) #hyperparameter priors
  tau <- sqrt(1/prec.tau2)
}", con="Multi.logit.jag")

y <- Vars$fix

x1 <-  Vars$h_polcon3

x2 <- Vars$imf_infl

x3 <- Vars$imf_ue

x4 <- Vars$imf_gd

x5 <- Vars$wdi_trade

x6 <- Vars$dr_eg

x7 <- Vars$wdi_gdppcgr

x8 <- Vars$dpi_erlc

N <- 607

country <- Vars$cname #specify levels
country <- as.factor(country)
nlevels(country) #Sample consists of 42 countries
country <- as.numeric(country) #transfer factor variabel to numeric variable in order to make model run
n <- 42

M.data.multi <-list('N'=N, 'n'= n, 'y'=y, 'country' = country, 'x1'=x1, 'x2'=x2, 'x3'=x3, 'x4'=x4, 'x5'=x5, 'x6'=x6, 'x7'=x7, 'x8'=x8)

library(coda)
library(rjags)
library(R2jags)
M.sim.multi <- jags(data=M.data.multi, parameters.to.save="beta", model.file="Multi.logit.jag", n.chains=3, n.iter=2000, n.burnin=500)
print(M.sim.multi)
```

and yields

```
Inference for Bugs model at "Multi.logit.jag", fit using jags,
 3 chains, each with 2000 iterations (first 500 discarded)
 n.sims = 4500 iterations saved
         mu.vect sd.vect    2.5%     25%     50%     75%   97.5%  Rhat n.eff
beta[1]    1.049   2.202  -3.081  -0.484   1.097   2.520   5.844 1.782     6
beta[2]    0.004   0.011  -0.017  -0.001   0.005   0.011   0.026 1.437     8
beta[3]    0.165   0.065   0.034   0.118   0.171   0.213   0.286 1.039    85
beta[4]   -0.035   0.011  -0.061  -0.042  -0.033  -0.027  -0.016 1.191    15
beta[5]    0.060   0.015   0.030   0.048   0.060   0.070   0.086 1.411     9
beta[6]    0.071   0.027   0.012   0.048   0.075   0.094   0.110 1.187    16
beta[7]   -0.140   0.053  -0.243  -0.178  -0.138  -0.105  -0.039 1.072    33
beta[8]   -0.037   0.186  -0.392  -0.171  -0.036   0.092   0.348 1.125    21
deviance 332.333   9.250 316.568 325.541 331.423 337.914 352.942 1.014   150

For each parameter, n.eff is a crude measure of effective sample size,
and Rhat is the potential scale reduction factor (at convergence, Rhat=1).

DIC info (using the rule, pD = var(deviance)/2)
pD = 42.2 and DIC = 374.6
DIC is an estimate of expected predictive error (lower deviance is better).
```

The glmer() model is the following:

```
library(Matrix)
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)
library(lmerTest)

Multi.freq <- glmer(fix ~ h_polcon3 + imf_infl + imf_ue + imf_gd + wdi_trade + dr_eg + wdi_gdppcgr + dpi_erlc + (1 | cname), family = binomial(link="logit"), data=Vars)
Multi.freq
```

and yields

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) [
glmerMod]
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: fix ~ h_polcon3 + imf_infl + imf_ue + imf_gd + wdi_trade + dr_eg +  
    wdi_gdppcgr + dpi_erlc + (1 | cname)
   Data: Vars
Control: glmerControl(optCtrl = list(maxfun = 20000))

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   446.6    490.7   -213.3    426.6      597 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.5707 -0.2023  0.0056  0.2251  6.7237 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 cname  (Intercept) 16.92    4.113   
Number of obs: 607, groups:  cname, 42

Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -10.640232   2.362286  -4.504 6.66e-06 ***
h_polcon3     1.025333   1.839488   0.557  0.57725    
imf_infl      0.004985   0.010386   0.480  0.63129    
imf_ue        0.183076   0.072181   2.536  0.01120 *  
imf_gd       -0.031592   0.011738  -2.692  0.00711 ** 
wdi_trade     0.048175   0.016842   2.860  0.00423 ** 
dr_eg         0.092837   0.029145   3.185  0.00145 ** 
wdi_gdppcgr  -0.118344   0.049786  -2.377  0.01745 *  
dpi_erlc     -0.100724   0.183591  -0.549  0.58326    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) h_plc3 imf_nf imf_ue imf_gd wd_trd dr_eg  wd_gdp
h_polcon3   -0.366                                                 
imf_infl    -0.077  0.104                                          
imf_ue      -0.346 -0.076  0.265                                   
imf_gd       0.052 -0.017 -0.214 -0.507                            
wdi_trade   -0.238  0.099 -0.193  0.193 -0.285                     
dr_eg       -0.585 -0.068 -0.304  0.038  0.043 -0.282              
wdi_gdppcgr  0.039 -0.109  0.157  0.040  0.123 -0.295  0.024       
dpi_erlc    -0.163  0.151 -0.216 -0.005  0.017  0.156 -0.033 -0.122
```

I am therefore suspicious that I made a mistake when setting up the data. Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

#### Update

I tried another, simpler approach (with removing e.obs), however, I still get different results for both the bayesian and the package-estimator:

```
b1.true <- 2.5 #individual level predictor coefficient
b2.true <- 1.75

mu.a.true <- 0.5
sigma.a.true <- 1.25 #among group variance

#Simulating the varying coefficients
J <- 10 #50 groups
u <- rnorm(J,0, 3) #group level predictor variable 
a.true <- rep (NA, J)
for (j in 1:J){
  a.true[j] <- rnorm (1, mu.a.true, sigma.a.true)
}

n <- 50 #number of observations
#set.seed(666)
country <- rep(1:J, n)
x1 <- rnorm(n) #individual level predictor variable
x2 <- rnorm(n)

y <- rep (NA, n) #dependent variable

for (i in 1:n){
  y[i] <- rbinom(n, 1, 1/(1+exp(-(a.true[country[i]] + b1.true*x1[i] + b2.true*x2[i]))))
}#prob. of the dependent variable described by a linear combination of covariates and country-specific intercepts 

#for (i in 1:n){
  #y[i] <- rnorm(1, a.true[country[i]] + b.true*x[i], sigma.y.true)
#}

Test <- data.frame(country, x1, x2, y)

#Apply Bayesian estimator to Test dataset

writeLines("
           model{
           for (i in 1:N){
           y[i] ~ dbin(p.bound[i], 1)
           p.bound[i] <- max(0, min(1, p[i]))
           logit(p[i]) <- Xbeta[i]  #likelihood
           Xbeta[i] <- beta0 + beta[1]*x1[i] +beta[2]*x2[i] + v[country[i]] 
           } #linear combination
           beta0 ~ dnorm(0,0.001) 
           beta[1] ~ dnorm(0,0.001) #IV priors
           beta[2] ~ dnorm(0,0.001)
           for (j in 1:n){
           v[j] ~ dnorm(mu.country, tau.country) #country-specific intercept
           }
           mu.country ~ dnorm(0,0.001) 
           tau.country <- pow(sigma.country, -2) #hyperparameter priors
           sigma.country ~ dunif(0, 100)
           }", con="Multi.logit.jag")

y <- Test$y

x1 <-  Test$x1

x2 <- Test$x2

N <- 500

country <- Test$country #specify levels
country <- as.factor(country)
nlevels(country) #10 groups
country <- as.numeric(country) #transfer factor variabel to numeric variable in order to make model run
n <- 10

M.data.test <-list('N'=N, 'n'= n, 'y'=y, 'country' = country, 'x1'=x1, 'x2'=x2)

library(coda)
library(rjags)
library(R2jags)
M.test <- jags(data=M.data.test, parameters.to.save="beta", model.file="Multi.logit.jag", n.chains=3, n.iter=2000, n.burnin=500)
print(M.test)
```

The results are still biased:

```
Inference for Bugs model at "Multi.logit.jag", fit using jags,
 3 chains, each with 2000 iterations (first 500 discarded)
 n.sims = 4500 iterations saved
         mu.vect sd.vect    2.5%     25%     50%     75%   97.5%  Rhat n.eff
beta[1]    3.901   0.524   2.938   3.530   3.859   4.256   5.008 1.008   280
beta[2]    1.575   0.245   1.121   1.402   1.570   1.736   2.078 1.002  1500
deviance 273.741   4.814 266.316 270.207 273.118 276.595 284.787 1.002  2100

For each parameter, n.eff is a crude measure of effective sample size,
and Rhat is the potential scale reduction factor (at convergence, Rhat=1).

DIC info (using the rule, pD = var(deviance)/2)
pD = 11.6 and DIC = 285.3
DIC is an estimate of expected predictive error (lower deviance is better).
```

Same for lme4:

```
#Test with package

library(Matrix)
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)
library(lmerTest)

Multi.freq <- glmer(y ~ x1 + x2 + (1 | country), family = binomial(link="logit"), data=Test, glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000)))
summary(Multi.freq)
```

Results:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) [
glmerMod]
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: y ~ x1 + x2 + (1 | country)
   Data: Test
Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 1e+05))

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   311.7    328.6   -151.9    303.7      496 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.00320 -0.18842 -0.01074  0.26742  2.08614 

Random effects:
 Groups  Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 country (Intercept) 6.721    2.593   
Number of obs: 500, groups:  country, 10

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   0.1587     0.8481   0.187    0.852    
x1            3.7344     0.5011   7.452 9.22e-14 ***
x2            1.5496     0.2422   6.397 1.58e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
   (Intr) x1   
x1 0.049       
x2 0.022  0.174
```

Comment: Could you add your model code as well?

Comment: I agree that the question isn't quite complete as it stands.  Q1: Is your `lme4` model `glmer(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7+x8+(1|country),data=Test,family=binomial)` ? Q2: are you primarily interested in the fixed-effect parameters? Q3: the most glaring possibility is the addition of `e.obs`; if you don't have an explicit observation-level random effect in the model, that will be a problem. Another common mistake (if you're interested in the random effects variances) is confusing variances and standard deviations.

Comment: `lme4::simulate(~x1+x2+...+(1|country),newdata=Test,newparam=list(theta=3,beta=c(0,2,3,...)),family=binomial)` should also work.

Comment: Finally, a common problem is to simulate a *single* example that happens to give estimates fairly far from the theoretical values (i.e., not realizing that the estimates might have large variance) - doing an ensemble is sometimes more useful

Comment: What happens if you remove `e.obs` when creating the data?  I might also try reducing the number of fixed effects to one, two or three when creating data and in the model (until you get it working) and increasing number of observations.  You had at least one Rhat that seemed kind of high, suggesting longer chains might help.  What are the estimates for the intercept when using Jags?  I think there should be two parameters for the intercept.

Comment: Actually you might get a separate intercept estimate for each country, but I think you should also have a mean and SD estimate for the intercept distribution.  It has been a while and this is all from memory.  Maybe I can check my copy of Gelman and Hill on Monday.